# Interprocess communication between a 2 applications

Tags: c#, com, ipc

I would like to transfer information between 2 process and the data that I pass between these 2 processes are COM visible types. What is the best way I can use to transfer information between these to processes. I know, we could do it using ***Named Pipes*** but not sure if we could transfer **types** using this. Can someone suggest a good resource that I can look into to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are looking to transfer objects between applications. You may want to look into .[NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28VS.71%29.aspx). The purpose of the remoting API is to allow access to types  from outside of the AppDomain or process in which they are created including accessing objects on remote hosts.